# how to set Windows media player 'express settings' programmatically?

Tags: c#, media-player, windows-media-player

Can anybody help me how to set the windows media player express settings programmatically? I have added reference for WMPLib and created a media player object and trying to play a file like wmp.OpenPlayer("c:\xxx.mp3");

Here the media player launches but on a Clean Windows XP SP3 machine, the media player asking to configure before playing the file. How to configure this programmatically or is there any way to skip this part and play the file?

Comment: What if the user doesn't want express settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is possibe according to [link](http://www.mydigitallife.info/skip-and-bypass-windows-media-player-initial-settings-wizard-on-first-run/). I haven't tested it though, so I'm not 100% sure if it works. You need to change some values in the registry. [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dwk5axy.aspx/) describes how to write to the registry. Hope this helps!